# How to create a restart dialog using install shield 2016?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installshield

how do I add an `installshield Restart dialog`?

I am using the `Installshield 2016 trial express version`
and the `Visual studio 2013`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set Windows Installer REBOOT property to "Force". Please see more: [REBOOT property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)